# Sort dictionary keys by value, then by key

Tags: swift

I'd like to iterate over the keys of a dictionary, sorted first by value (descending), and then by key (ascending)
`let dict = ["foo" : 1, "bar" : 1, "baz" : 2, "qux" : 2]`

The order of the iteration should be:
`["baz", "qux", "bar", "foo"]`

I'd like to print:

```
baz 2
qux 2
bar 1
foo 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Xcode 13.2.1 • Swift 5.5.2**

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable, Value: Comparable {
    var valueKeySorted: [(Key, Value)] {
        sorted {
            $0.value != $1.value ?
            $0.value > $1.value :
            $0.key < $1.key
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let dict = ["foo" : 1, "bar" : 1, "baz" : 2, "qux" : 2]

let keyValueArray = dict.valueKeySorted

print(keyValueArray)   // "[("baz", 2), ("qux", 2), ("bar", 1), ("foo", 1)]"

for (key, value) in keyValueArray {
    print(key, value)
}
```

Comment: That's an awesome one-liner.

Comment: @ChrisKoknat I think the best would be let keyValueArray = dict.sort { $0.1 != $1.1 ? $0.1 > $1.1 : $0.0 < $1.0 }

Comment: Best because one call to `sort` is faster than two?

Comment: Thanks, it save a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let dict = ["foo" : 1, "bar" : 1, "baz" : 2, "qux" : 2]

let result = dict.map { (key: $0.0, value: $0.1) }
                 .sort { 
                    if $0.value != $1.value {
                        return $0.value > $1.value
                    }
                    return $0.key < $1.key
                  }

for r in result {
    print("\(r.key) \(r.value)")
}
```

`map` transforms the dictionary into an array of tuples `(key: "foo", value: 1)` etc. It then becomes a matter of sorting that array with `sort`.

Comment: No need use map. You can do it apply sort directly to your dictionary.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I prefer my data structures to have proper names rather then referring to them by their positional value. Hence the `map`

Comment: Gives the following error Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call