# Sort swift dictionary by value and then sort the final result by key for keys having the same value

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of [myStruct:Int] which I want to sort first by the value and then second for keys with the same value, i want to sort them by a string attribute 'item' in 'myStruct'

```
struct myStruct {
    var item: String!
    var amount: Int!
}
```

I tried to implement the suggestion [Swift: Sort dictionary keys by value, then by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882057/swift-sort-dictionary-keys-by-value-then-by-key), which is an awesome solution IMO, but i cannot implement it for the custom struct I have.

Any help please?

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Show what you have tried so far. Show some sample data and show what result you want from that data.

Comment: You can't have a dictionary like that because `myStruct` is not `Hashable`. Please make sure the previous code does compile before implementing new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement referenced solution with sorting closures, you should define corresponding comparison operator for your structure

```
func < (lhs: myStruct, rhs: myStruct) -> Bool {
  return lhs.item < rhs.item 
}
```

Comment: This answer and the one from @Alain T. combined solved my problem. I had to make the Struct hashable and then add this function. Once I did that, i was able to use the one liner from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882057/swift-sort-dictionary-keys-by-value-then-by-key) with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you make your struct hashable so that it can be a key to your dictionary and comparable so that it cna be sorted, you can sort a dictionary by value and key using the following sort parameters:

```
let dict   = [ "A" : 1, "B" : 2, "C" : 2, "D" : 2, "E" : 1 ]
for (key,value) in dict.sort({ $0.1 == $1.1 ? $0.0 < $1.0 : $0.1 < $1.1 })
{
  print("\(value),\(key)")
}
// prints:
// 1,A
// 1,E
// 2,B
// 2,C
// 2,D
```