# Sort NSDictionary first by value then by key

Tags: objective-c, sorting, dictionary

So I have a NSNumber dictionary similar to this (keys already added in order):

```
1 : @2000,
2 : @2000,
4 : @1000,
5 : @1000,
6 : @3000
```

And I want both values and keys to be sorted in ascending order with the order of the values having the higher priority. (Resulting ordered keys and values being in separate arrays of course as dictionaries aren't ordered as mentioned by @rmaddy).
Result should be:

```
4 : 1000,
5 : 1000,
1 : 2000,
2 : 2000,
6 : 3000
```

I can already get the keys sorted by value using

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *sortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

but this doesn't respect the order of the keys of course.

**Disclaimer: The solution to this problem in Swift is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882057/swift-sort-dictionary-keys-by-value-then-by-key) but I can't figure out how to implement that in Obj-C**

Comment: Dictionaries have no order.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I know. But if I were to output the keys, they would be in the order I added them to the dictionary

Comment: Not necessarily. The keys can be displayed in any order. It has nothing to do with the order they were added.

Comment: @rmaddy Hm, I don't know about that. In my tests they seemed to behave like that. But it basically makes no difference for the question

Comment: @rmaddy I just wanted to mention that side fact as it may simplify the problem

Comment: Then what's your question? You know that dictionaries can't be sorted. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy. Dictionary shouldn't have order since it's not index base (like Array), but key based. (to access the value).

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, if I wasn't clear enough. I want two arrays, one containing the keys and the other containing the corresponding values and both should be in the order as described in the question

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you want two separate arrays where one is the sorted values of the dictionary and the other is the keys sorted to correspond with the values. Additionally, two keys associated with the same values should be sorted in the natural order of the two keys.

Sorting the values is easy. But there is nothing built in to get the corresponding keys sorted in the manner you want. The issue is getting keys for equal values sorted in order of the key. The code below is one solution that gives the desired results.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@1 : @2000,
                      @2 : @2000,
                      @4 : @1000,
                      @5 : @1000,
                       @6 : @3000};

NSArray *sortedValues = [dict.allValues sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSOrderedSet *uniqueValues = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:sortedValues];
NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dict.count];
for (id val in uniqueValues) {
    NSArray *keys = [dict allKeysForObject:val];
    [sortedKeys addObjectsFromArray:[keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
}

NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);
NSLog(@"keys: %@, values: %@", sortedKeys, sortedValues);
```

This outputs:

```
dict: {
    6 = 3000;
    2 = 2000;
    5 = 1000;
    1 = 2000;
    4 = 1000;
}
keys: (
    4,
    5,
    1,
    2,
    6
), values: (
    1000,
    1000,
    2000,
    2000,
    3000
)
```

Comment: That's what I already managed to achieve, but that's not completely what I want. "keysSortedByValueUsingSelector" returns me the keys in the order of the corresponding values but that does't imply, that the keys themselves are also ordered. It COULD return "4,5,1,2,6" (what I want) but that's not always the case. Sometimes it returns something like "5,4,2,1,6" depending on the size of the dictionary, as it is only respecting the order of the values.

Comment: I'm sorry if I fail to explain this comprehensible. Please visit the link above, it's basically the same problem. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: But both of those results for the sorted keys are really the same thing. Whether it's `4,5,...` or `5,4,...` doesn't matter since both values at those indexes are same.

Comment: It DOES matter for me, that's my problem. I want those keys that have the same value to be also ordered. So "4,5,1,2,6" is the only valid solution in my case

Comment: It's like alphabetic ordering of words: "Ant,Apple" - both have the same first letter but "n" comes before "p".

Comment: OK, every bit of information you have added in comments to this answer and below your question needs to be put into your question so everyone can see it and better understand your question and what results you expect and need.

Comment: My updated answer gives the desired results assuming I understand your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! I'll give it a try and update my question tomorrow, it's too late for me right now

Comment: I didn't know about NSOrderedSet, but it seems like a logical and elegant solution in my case, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a data structure that is sortable:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@1 : @2000,
                    @2 : @2000,
                    @4 : @1000,
                    @5 : @1000,
                    @6 : @3000};

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id key in [d allKeys]) {
    [array addObject:@[key, d[key]]];
}
```

That will give us:

```
@[ @[@6, @3000], @[@2, @2000], ...]
```

Now, we can write a comparator that compares however you like.  What I understand from the OP is that we want the primary sort on value with a secondary (tie-breaking) sort on keys:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id elementA, id elementB) {
    NSNumber *valueA = ((NSArray *)elementA)[1];
    NSNumber *valueB = ((NSArray *)elementB)[1];
    if ([valueA isEqualToNumber:valueB]) {
        NSNumber *keyA = ((NSArray *)elementA)[0];
        NSNumber *keyB = ((NSArray *)elementB)[0];
        return [keyA compare:keyB];
    } else {
        return [valueA compare:valueB];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"%@", array);
```